# Difference on image rendering over different android version

Tags: android, css, html, image, sencha-touch-2

í'm trying to build a image gallery using Sencha Touch.
I create a container object with hbox layout and width equal to window.innerWidth. Then, i add three containers inside it. Each one using vbox layout and with width equal to window.innerWidth / 3.

I add images in it with width equal to the column width and height setted on CSS to 'auto'.

This is my code:

```
Ext.define('Oasis.view.ImgTest',{
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype:'mosaic',
config:{
    cls: 'gallery',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox', // This is a column-based mosaic
        pack: 'center',
        align: 'start'
    },
    columnWidth: -1,//
    numCols: 3, // Number of columns
    lastColumnUsed: -1, // Last column where a image were added. -1 for none.
    autoInstanceColumns: false, // If true, instantiate each column on initialize method
    items:[],
    scrollable: {
        direction: 'vertical',
        directionLock : true
    }
},
initialize: function(){
    var me = this;

    me.setColumnWidth(window.innerWidth/me.getNumCols());

    Ext.Viewport.on('orientationchange', function(){
        // Updates columns widths on screen orientation changes
        me.setColumnWidth(window.innerWidth/me.getNumCols());
        for(var c = 0; c < me.getNumCols();c++){
            // Column
            var column = me.getAt(c);
            for(var i = 0; i < column.getItems().getCount();i++){
                // Items per column
                var element = column.getAt(i);
                element.setWidth(me.getColumnWidth());
            }
        }
    }, this, {buffer: 50 });

    // Creates all columns and add to the mosaic
    if(me.getAutoInstanceColumns())
        for(var i = 0; i < me.getNumCols();i++){
            me.add({
                xtype:'container',
                id: 'col-'+i,
                cls: 'gallery',
                layout: 'vbox',
                flex:1
            });
        }


    // Add images
    me.insert(Ext.create('Ext.Img',{
            src:'resources/images/0228_FEA_Pet_dog_WCGHS_cutt.jpg',
            cls: 'mosaicitem',
            mode: 'element'
        }));me.insert(Ext.create('Ext.Img',{
            src:'resources/images/027c076a1c-1152x864.jpg',
            cls: 'mosaicitem',
            mode: 'element'
        }));me.insert(Ext.create('Ext.Img',{
            src:'resources/images/0913_LIF_PET_DOG_CUTTY_WCG.jpg',
            cls: 'mosaicitem',
            mode: 'element'
        }));
},
__get_next_column_index: function(){
    var me = this;
    var column = 0;

    // If some column was used in the last iteraction (if there was one),
    // calculates the next column that should be used. Else, use column 0.
    if(me.getLastColumnUsed() >= 0){
        column = (me.getLastColumnUsed() + 1) % me.getNumCols();
    }


    return column
},
insert: function(element){
    var me = this;

    // Se as colunas não forem instanciadas logo na initialização da classe, instancia uma a uma até que todas estejam instanciadas.
    if(!me.getAutoInstanceColumns() && me.getItems().getCount() < me.getNumCols()){
        var column = me.getItems().getCount();
        target_column = me.add({
                xtype:'container',
                id: 'col-'+column,
                cls: 'column',
                flex:1
            });
    }else{
        var column = me.__get_next_column_index();
        var target_column = me.getAt(column);
    }   

    // Set element width
    element.setWidth(me.getColumnWidth());
    target_column.add(element);
    me.setLastColumnUsed(column);
},
```

})

This is my CSS:

```
.gallery {
line-height: 0;
-webkit-column-gap: 0px;
margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
height: 100%;
}
.mosaicitem {
height:auto !important; 
border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: fadein 1s, translateZ 0.6s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
   -moz-animation: fadein 1s, translateZ 0.6s; /* Firefox */
   -moz-animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
    -ms-animation: fadein 1s, translateZ 0.6s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
     -o-animation: fadein 1s, translateZ 0.6s; /* Opera */
     -o-animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
        animation: fadein 1s, translateZ 0.6s;
        animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0 ; }
to   { opacity: 1 ; }
}
@keyframes translateZ {
from { top : 100px ; }
to   { top: 0px ; }
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0 ; }
to   { opacity: 1 ; }
}
@-moz-keyframes translateZ {
from { top : 100px ; }
to   { top: 0px ; }
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0 ; }
to   { opacity: 1 ; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes translateZ {
from { top : 100px ; }
to   { top: 0px ; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0 ; }
to   { opacity: 1 ; }
}​
@-ms-keyframes translateZ {
from { top : 100px ; }
to   { top: 0px ; }
}

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0 ; }
to   { opacity: 1 ; }
}​
@-o-keyframes translateZ {
from { top : 100px ; }
to   { top: 0px ; }
}
```

On devices running android 4.4.2 it works perfectly. However, on android 4.2.2 it look as if the height was set to 100% or something like that.

This is a comparison on android emulator.
[image]

What's happening here?

Comment: Do you really want to find out what's wrong in your code, or would it be fine to suggest another approach to achieve the same result?

Comment: First thing that I notice in your code is that you are misusing layouts. When you use layout on a container its childs are automatically sized (width if parent has hbox or height if parent has vbox) so you don't really need to do those calculation.

Comment: Another approach to achieve the same result would be great =)

Comment: Can you put it to a sencha fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `mosaicitem` class in your CSS sets the `height` attribute to be `auto`. That means you let the browser rezise the image. Obviously, you will have different results on different browser. I don't know exactly how the two browsers react to your setting, but it can only come from this.

Taken from Sencha's Doc about the `Ext.Image` `height` property:

> By default, if this is not explicitly set, this Component's element
>   will simply have its own natural size.

So I believe that this line is imposing a height with your !important tag, and overrides sencha's automatic height which should be the image's natural size.

In short, try removing this line.